# Bash Completion only from beginning (^...$)?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I've wrote a simple bash completion script to complete ssh servernames from a list, eg:

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(cat $hosts | awk -F';' '{print $2}')

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

the $opts list is sth like:

```
locationX-apache-01.local.lan
locationY-apache-02.local.lan
locationX-mysql-01.local.lan
locationY-mysql-02.local.lan
```

Bash completion is working as expected if I write eg `$ ssh loca<TAB>` ... But how can I get suggestions if I don't start from the beginning like this:
`$ ssh apac<TAB>` to get the 2 apache servers from the list above:

```
locationX-apache-01.local.lan
locationY-apache-02.local.lan
```

Comment: Don't forget about a possible `ssh user@host`. You'll need to split `$cur` in `user` and `host` parts, match the `host`, then append the `user` to the result.

Comment: Put your hosts in your `.ssh/config` file and the default bash completion will pick them up and use them.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
: ${cur:="."}
COMPREPLY=( $( grep "$cur" "$hosts"  | awk -F';' '{print $2}' ) )
```

The first line sets cur to "." (the regexp wildcard) in case it's not set.  Then we just look for any matching string in the $hosts file.  The functionality will feel a little different to end users, but I think this will give you what you are looking for.

Combining my edit with your code you get:

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur 
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    : ${cur:="."}
    COMPREPLY=( $( grep "$cur" "$hosts"  | awk -F';' '{print $2}' ) )

    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not like the solution… I am using zsh, is there a better way with zsh autocompletion maybe?